# Computation failed in `stat_signif()`: data are essentially constant

Tags: r, ggplot2, comparison, boxplot, p-value

I am trying to make a boxplot and I want to see the group comparisons however for some reason it is not showing up

```
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data2, aes(wcc_group, 2750.3)) +
geom_boxplot() +
geom_quasirandom(aes(colour = as.factor(X28_day_mortality) , shape = sex, fill = 
as.factor(X28_day_mortality)), groupOnX = FALSE) +
labs(x = "WCC Group", y = "Apolipoprotein A-I", title = "Expression of Apolipoprotein A-I in WCC 
Groups", fill = "Mortality", shape = "Sex", colour = "Mortality") +  stat_compare_means(method = 
"t.test", comparisons = list(c("Low", "Medium"), c("Low", "High"), c("Medium", "High") ), aes(label = 
..p.signif..)) +
 scale_colour_manual(values =c("red", "black")) +
 scale_fill_manual(values =c("red", "black")) +
 scale_shape_manual(values =c(24,22))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq5XC.png)

Any reason why this error keeps showing up?

Comment: I failed to reproduce the error you encountered because `data2` which you used in your code is not found. Could you provide `data2` or instead provide a minimal, reproducible example that represents your problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the y-value in your example, you have it as 2750.3, is there a reason for this?

This singular y-value is why the black line is drawn for each of the groups. It is not a boxplot because there is only one value-- can't have a Q1, median, Q3, etc. If you were to have y-values be values for that variable (Apolipoprotein A-I?), then the boxplot will be able to show the distribution of the scores.

The t-test won't work and kicks an error for a similar reason-- there is no variance to calculate the t-test value since the only value for y is 2750.3.

```
ggplot(data = data2, aes(wcc_group, [enter associated protein var here])) +
geom_boxplot() +
geom_quasirandom(aes(colour = as.factor(X28_day_mortality) , shape = sex, fill = 
as.factor(X28_day_mortality)), groupOnX = FALSE) +
labs(x = "WCC Group", y = "Apolipoprotein A-I", title = "Expression of Apolipoprotein A-I in WCC 
Groups", fill = "Mortality", shape = "Sex", colour = "Mortality") +  stat_compare_means(method = 
"t.test", comparisons = list(c("Low", "Medium"), c("Low", "High"), c("Medium", "High") ), aes(label = 
..p.signif..)) +
 scale_colour_manual(values =c("red", "black")) +
 scale_fill_manual(values =c("red", "black")) +
 scale_shape_manual(values =c(24,22))
```